# Fluent.EntityError error 0

Tags: ios, swift, vapor

I'm new to vapor and I'm stucked. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.xplusz.com/how-to-do-basic-crud/ but I'm using a MySQL database instead of a postgresql database.

So this is the code I have:
Patient.swift

```
import Foundation
import Vapor
import Fluent


final class Patient: Model {

  var id: Node?
  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String
  var exists: Bool = false

  init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    self.id = nil
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
  }

  init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
    id = try node.extract("id")
    firstName = try node.extract("first_name")
    lastName = try node.extract("last_name")
  }

  func makeNode(context: Context) throws -> Node {
    return try Node(node: [
      "id": id,
      "first_name": firstName,
      "last_name": lastName
      ])
  }

  static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
    try database.create("patients") { users in
      users.id()
      users.string("first_name")
      users.string("last_name")
    }
  }

  static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
  try database.delete("patients")
  }

}
```

main.swift

```
import Vapor
import VaporMySQL

let drop = Droplet(
  providers:[VaporMySQL.Provider.self]
)

drop.get { req in
    return try drop.view.make("welcome", [
        "message": drop.localization[req.lang, "welcome", "title"]
    ])
}


drop.get("version"){request in
  if let db = drop.database?.driver as? MySQLDriver{
    let version = try db.raw("SELECT version()")
    return try JSON(node: version)
  }else{
    return "No db connection"
  }
}

drop.post("patients") { request in
  print(request.json)
  var patient = try Patient(node: request.json)
  try patient.save()
  return patient
}

drop.get("patients"){request in
  return try JSON(node: Patient.all().makeNode())
}




drop.resource("posts", PostController())

drop.run()
```

If I run version, everything works fine:

```
[
  {
    "version()": "5.7.14"
  }
]
```

But for example if I run post or get requests, I get an error:
[image]

The tutorial didn't talk about creating a table in the database first, but thats what the prepare function is about right? What else is wrong?

mysql.json

```
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "user": "root",
  "password": "",
  "database": "development",
  "port": "3306",
  "encoding": "utf8"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a issue related to naming conversion. In postman you are sending parameters named "**firstName**" & "**lastName**" and in your model class you are using parameters which are underscore separated like "**first_name**" & "**last_name**", you should follow same naming conversion.

**Update:-**

Try in below way and let me know if you are still facing this error.

```
    guard let first_name = request.data["first_name"]?.string, let last_name = request.data["last_name"]?.string else {
        return try JSON(node:[
            "error": true,
            "message": "first_name or last_name not found"
            ])
    }

    var patient = Patient(firstName: first_name, lastName: last_name)
    do {
        try patient.save()

        return try JSON(node:[
            "error" : false,
            "message" : "patient added successfully"
            ])

    } catch let error{
        return try JSON(node:[
            "error" : true,
            "message" : "\(error)"
            ])
    }
```

**Update 2:-**

One should add provider and prepare data base, before use.

```
try drop.addProvider(VaporMySQL.Provider.self)
drop.preparations = [Patient.self]
```

Comment: I changed it to first_name and last_name and get the same error

Comment: This is most definitely related to the `init(node: Node...)` method trying to extract `first_name` but the JSON body contains `firstName`. The keys need to match exactly.

Comment: it throws an error with message "noDatabase". But the version thing still works

Comment: you need to create a data base in mysql -> using command create database databasename; -> have you create a database to use? + please also show your mysql.json file here.

Comment: The database exists, I use sequel pro to connect to it and it works.

Comment: you can join this  http://vapor.team  and try at #mysql channel, or try to repeat whole process again :(

Comment: `noDatabase` means you haven't added the model as a preparation. The `Patient.database` property gets set that way (or you can set it manually).

Comment: @TannerNelson what do you mean?  what should I do? do you have an example?